# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, android

I'm building an Android app to quiz people on subjects, the backend is written in Java and it reads and parses CSV file (hard coded URL) , and the front end is my Android app.

Here is my error:

```
05-08 01:19:00.792: E/AndroidRuntime(790): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{cs314.adamnick.p4/cs314.adamnick.p4.QuizTakerGUI}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-08 01:19:00.792: E/AndroidRuntime(790):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
05-08 01:19:00.792: E/AndroidRuntime(790):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
05-08 01:19:00.792: E/AndroidRuntime(790):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
05-08 01:19:00.792: E/AndroidRuntime(790):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
05-08 01:19:00.792: E/AndroidRuntime(790):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-08 01:19:00.792: E/AndroidRuntime(790):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-08 01:19:00.792: E/AndroidRuntime(790):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
05-08 01:19:00.792: E/AndroidRuntime(790):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-08 01:19:00.792: E/AndroidRuntime(790):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
05-08 01:19:00.792: E/AndroidRuntime(790):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
05-08 01:19:00.792: E/AndroidRuntime(790):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
05-08 01:19:00.792: E/AndroidRuntime(790):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-08 01:19:00.792: E/AndroidRuntime(790): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-08 01:19:00.792: E/AndroidRuntime(790):  at wharehouse.QuizAndroidGUI.<init>(QuizAndroidGUI.java:36)
05-08 01:19:00.792: E/AndroidRuntime(790):  at cs314.adamnick.p4.QuizTakerGUI.onCreate(QuizTakerGUI.java:38)
05-08 01:19:00.792: E/AndroidRuntime(790):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
05-08 01:19:00.792: E/AndroidRuntime(790):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
05-08 01:19:00.792: E/AndroidRuntime(790):  ... 11 more
```

Which causes my program to crash.

Here's my class:

```
public class QuizTakerGUI extends Activity {

    private RadioButton answer1;
    private RadioButton answer2;
    private RadioButton answer3;
    private RadioButton answer4;

    private Button submit; 
    private Button previous; 
    private Button next; 
    private Button finish; 

    private TextView questionArea; 

    private QuizAndroidGUI dataWharehouse;
    private QuizQuestion currentQuestion;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz_taker);

        dataWharehouse = new QuizAndroidGUI(this);

        answer1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.answer1);
        answer2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.answer2);
        answer3 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.answer3);
        answer4 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.answer4);

        questionArea = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.quizQuestion); 


        submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submitAnswer);
        previous = (Button) findViewById(R.id.prev);
        next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.next);
        finish = (Button) findViewById(R.id.finish);

        submit.setOnClickListener(submitHandler);
        previous.setOnClickListener(previousHandler);
        next.setOnClickListener(nextHandler);
        finish.setOnClickListener(finishHandler);
    }
```

Here's my datawhare house class:

```
public QuizAndroidGUI(QuizTakerGUI app){
    URL path = ClassLoader.getSystemResource("questions.csv");
    this.androidApplication = app; 
    NUMBERofQUIZES = 10; 
    // since we implement quiz ui we pass in the current program 
    quizTaker = new QuizTaker(this);
    try {
        // passing in the csv file hard coded 
        parser = new QuestionParser(new File(path.toURI()));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        parser = null; 
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    quizTaker.startAndDisplayQuiz("Android Quiz", this.NUMBERofQUIZES, this.parser);
}
```

I think the issue maybe caused because the parser is getting set to null.

Comment: You got the `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />` in the manifest?

Comment: Please highlight the QuizAndroidGUI.java:36 line.

Comment: ClassLoader.getSystemResource ? What's the purpose?

Comment: Where is "questions.csv" stored? in Assets? If so you should be accessing it through `InputStream is = getAssets().open(filename);`

Comment: Why don't you just debug your app?

Comment: To load a CSV which acts as a database of quiz questions.

Comment: Android has its own way. Why don't you use assets or raw folder?

Comment: @Snow_Mac : What line is line 38 of `QuizTakerGUI.onCreate(...)`?

Comment: Line 36 is:         parser = new QuestionParser(new File(path.toURI()));

Comment: Line 38:   dataWharehouse = new QuizAndroidGUI(this);

Comment: @blackbelt I am not similar with android, what do I do for assets?

Comment: assets is an internal app folder (you can see it in Eclipse as part of the directory hierarchy). put your cvs file inside it and open this way AssetManager am = context.getAssets();
InputStream fs = am.open("questions.cvs");. Use the InputStream to load it in memory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the **`questions.csv`** file into your classpath and do this:

```
ClassLoader loader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
URL resource = loader.getResource("myfile");
```

To load the file properly.

Comment: How do I put into my class path?

Comment: You have several ways to do that. Are you using eclipse?

Comment: Then just drag and drop the file into your project. You should be able to load it correctly then. Take a look at the relative path the file is given into eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Not enough line info but I suspect that `ClassLoader.getSystemResource("questions.csv")` isn't what you really wanted, it's highly unusual to see it in android at least in my experience.

I would put the file in `assets` directory and use [AssetManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getAssets%28%29) to read the file.

Comment: Is there a way to use asset manager in a file that is not an android app? I have an application that is non-android that is written in Java that must take an argument of a file to return to me quiz questions.

Comment: Unfortunately no, but you create an interface for reading and decide which implementation to use based on which platform you're on.